# parsing json array in javascript with unknown field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have found a lot of threads here on StackOverflow that talk about parsing json arrays but I can't seem to figure out how to get back some of the data. Here is what I have...

```
    $('#keyword_form').submit(function(e){  
        var gj = $.post('employee_search.php',$('#keyword_form').serialize(),function(data){                
            if(!data || data.status !=1 )
            {
                alert(data.message);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        },'json');  
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

The json data being sent to it looks like this...

```
{
    "status":1,
    "message":"Query executed in 9.946837 seconds.",
    "usernames_count":{
        "gjrowe":5,
        "alisonrowe":4,
        "bob":"1"
    }
}
```

As my function shows I can do `alert(data.message);` but how can I access the `usernames_count` data?

My confusion comes from the fact that the data has no name/label. `bob` is a username and `1` is the returned count associated with that username

If I do `alert(usernames_count);` I get back `[object Object]`

If I do `alert(usernames_count[0]);` I get back `undefined`

I am sure I should be doing something with `JSON.parse();` but I haven't gotten it right yet

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the returned data? `usernames_count` should really be a number and a new `users` field should be an array holding users. Don't you think?

Comment: One thing that may be confusing you is that usernames_count is not an array, it is a JSON object.

Comment: It's a JavaScript object, therefore you can iterate the keys – with a `for…in` or `Object.keys`. In ES6 you have also `for…of`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or a [for…in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop – remember in that case to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
var users = data.usernames_count;
Object.keys(users).forEach(function(user) {
    console.log(user, users[user]);
});
```

Comment: Remember that this is not supported in all older browsers. There's a guide on how to add backwards capability [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @HannesJohansson If it is not supported on older browsers, am I safer to use the other answer that uses jquery?

Comment: If you have no problem on relying on jQuery, sure. And it seems you are using jQuery anyway, so I'd pick that solution. If you want code that doesn't depend on jQuery, though, you could patch Object like in the Mozilla guide.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$.each(data.usernames_count, function(username, val) {
    alert(username+" has a value of "+val);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your question is how to iterate over the entries in the `usernames_count` object. You can do that like so:

```
var key = '';
for(key in data.usernames_count) {

    //check that this key isn't added from the prototype
    if(data.usernames_count.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        var value = data.usernames_count[key];

        //do something with the key and value
    }
}
```